# square of a real number is always positive

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing

I was working on a problem and had to prove firsthand that $a^2>0$ if $a$ is not $0$ and I did not find anything on the site that gave a proof using the properties I'm using so I was wondering if mine was good:

$P$ is the set of all positive numbers

**Case 1**

If $a>0$ then $(a-0) = a\in P$.

Then $(a-0)a\in P$ *(closure under multiplication)*

$\Rightarrow (a^2 -0)\in P \Rightarrow a^2>0$

**Case 2**

If $a<0$ then $(0-a) = -a\in P$.

Then $-a(0-a)\in P$ *(closure under multiplication)*

$\Rightarrow (0 + a^2)\in P$ *considering $((-a)(-b) = ab)$*

$\Rightarrow (a^2 -(-0)) = (a^2 - 0)\in P \Rightarrow a^2>0$

I feel like $(-a)(-b) = ab$ kind of implies what I'm trying to prove...

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Yes. This is correct. But, before using (-1)(-1) = 1, you have to prove it as well. Try proving it. Then you will also have to prove that (-a) = (-1)a. This will be sufficient to prove the case 2.

Comment: The choice of $a-0$ instead of just $a$ seems a bit clunky, everything you said works with just $a$. Otherwise everything is good

Comment: How do you know that $P$ is closed under multiplication ? It seems to me that all the difficulty lies in that property.

Comment: which are the axioms you use to define $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @nicomezi this can be viewed as an axiom, http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L5.html or https://sites.math.washington.edu/~hart/m524/realprop.pdf or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach

Comment: Why do you think you need express $a$ as $a-0$ in your first case? From $a>0$ and the $x\gt 0,y\gt 0 \Rightarrow xy \gt 0$ (=closed under multiplication axiom) immediately follows $a\cdot a\gt 0$ if you set both $x$ and $y$ to $a$.

Comment: The question is what prior knowledge are you allowed to use? Depending on that the proof could be verything from "it's obvious" to be a whole book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What axioms are you using?  How was $P$ closed under multiplication proven?  I think your answers are probably correct if those indeed are the axioms and properties actually available to you (they are, of course correct) however I think the use of $a-0$ and $0-a$ was clunky and unnecessary.

That standard method is that you are given axioms

$a < b \implies a+x < b+x$

and $x > 0; a < b \implies ax < bx$

And you have that additive and multiplitive identities inverses exist and distribution property applies.

From that you can prove:

i) $-(-a) = a$ Pf:  $-a + a = 0;  - a + -(-a) = 0$.  (It's an axiom that additive inverses always exist.)  So $a + (-a) + a = a + (-a) + -(-a)\implies 0 + a = 0 + -(-a) \implies a = -(-a)$.

ii) If $a > 0$ then $-a < 0$ (and vice versa).  Pf: $a > 0 \implies a+(-a) > 0 - a \implies 0 > -a$.

iii) $x*(-y) = -xy$.  Pf:  Let $x*(-y)+ xy = x(-y + y) = x*0 = 0$ (Oops, we must also prove $a*0 = 0$.  See addendum). And there for $-xy = x*(-y)$.

iv)  $x^2 \ge 0$ with equalition holding only if $x = 0$.

Pf:  Case 1:  $x > 0$ then $x*x > x*0 =0$.

Case 2: $x = 0$ then $x^2 = 0$.

Case 3: $x < 0$ then $-x > 0$ and $x*(-x) < 0$ so $-x^2 < 0$ and $x^2 > 0$.

v)  $1 > 0$ Pf:  $1 \ne 0$ and $1^2 = 1$.

===

Addendum.  $a*(0) = a*(0 + 0) = a*(0) + a*(0)$.  So $a*(0) + (-a*(0)) = a*(0) + a*(0) + (-a*(0)) \implies 0 = a*0 + 0 = a*0$.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**:

Let $a$ be positive and note that $-a=(-1)a$. Then by associativity of the multiplication,

$$(-a)^2=(-1)^2a^2=a^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Proposition 10 is the requested result.

**Introduction**

$+$ is a binary operations from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,$-$ 
is a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\frac 1 .$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $0$ and $1$ are from $\mathbb{R}$
, $0 \ne 1$

In tthe Axiom section the tags on the right side are the names of the axioms. So the associative law of the $+$ operator is called $(\text{AddAssoc})$

The propositions have names $(\text{P1})$ to $(\text{P10})$.
In the proofs the tag on the right side is the name of the axiom that is used to get from the current line to the next line. So in the proof of proposal 1 to get from the first line 
$$a\cdot 0$$
to the second line 
$$0\cdot a+0 $$
one uses axiom $(\text{A2})$
$$a=a+0$$
where we substitue $a$ by $0\cdot a$
to get
$$0\cdot a= 0\cdot a +0$$

In the proofs propositions 1 to 6 and 8 the expression in a line is a real number that is equal to the real number  of the next line or an inequality holds. 
Proposition 7 and  9 are more complex. These are equivalent logical expressions. Proposition 10 is the most complex. It is an indirect proof where we deduce a contradiction from some assumptions.

$(\text{def})$ means that is a definition or an abbreviation that is used here, e.g. $a^2$ is an abbreviation for $a\cdot a$. We do not explicitly state this definition in this text but assume they are known to the reader.

Propositions 1 to 4 are valid for all fields. Propositions 5 to 10 need the order axioms for their proofs.

Maybe it is also useful to read the post from the bottom to the end, so starting with propostion 10 that is the statement asked by the OP.

**Axioms**

$$a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c \tag{AddAssoc}$$
$$0+a=a \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$a+0=a \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$a+(-a)=0 \tag{AddInv}$$
$$(-a)+a=0 \tag{AddInv}$$
$$a+b=b+a \tag{AddComm}$$

$$a \cdot (b \cdot c)=(a \cdot b) \cdot c \tag{MulAssoc}$$
$$1 \cdot a=a \tag{MulIdent}$$
$$a \cdot 1=a \tag{MulIdent}$$
$$a \cdot \frac 1 a =1 \tag{MulInv}$$
$$\frac 1 a \cdot a   =1 \tag{MulInv}$$
$$a \cdot b=b \cdot a \tag{MulComm}$$

$$a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b + a \cdot c \tag{Distrib}$$
$$(a+b) \cdot c =a\cdot c + b \cdot c \tag{Distrib}$$

These axioms define a **field**.

$$a<0 \; \lor a=0  \; \lor a>0 \tag{OrdTrich}$$
$$a>0 \;  \land  \; b>0 \Rightarrow a\cdot b >0 \tag{OrdMulClose}$$
$$ a<b \Rightarrow a+c \; < \; b+c\tag{OrdTranInv}$$

This is an **ordered field** now. For our investigations we do not need the completeness axiom that holds in a **complete ordered field**.

**Proposition 1**
$$a\cdot 0=0 \tag{P1}$$
**Proof**
$$ 0\cdot a \tag{AddIdent} $$
$$ =0\cdot a+0  \tag{AddInv} $$
$$=0\cdot a+(0\cdot a+(-(0\cdot a)))  \tag{AddAssoc}$$
$$=(0\cdot a+0\cdot a)+(-(0\cdot a))  \tag{Distrib}$$
$$=(0+0)\cdot a+(-(0\cdot a )) \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$=0\cdot a+(-(0\cdot a))  \tag{AddInv}$$
$$=0$$

**Proposition 2**:
$$(-1)^2=1 \tag{P2}$$
**Proof**:
$$(-1)^2 \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$=(-1)^2+0 \tag{AddInv}$$
$$=(-1)^2+((-1)+1) \tag{AddAssoc}$$
$$=((-1)^2+(-1))+1 \tag{MulIdent}$$
$$=((-1)^2+(-1)\cdot 1)+1 \tag{Distrib}$$
$$=(-1)((-1)+1)+1 \tag{AddInv}$$
$$=(-1)\cdot 0+1 \tag{P1}$$
$$=0+1 \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$=1$$

**Proposition 3**
$$-a=(-1)a \tag{P3}$$
**Proof**
$$-a \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$=-a+0 \tag{P1}$$
$$=-a+0\cdot a \tag{AddInv}$$
$$=-a+(1+(-1))\cdot a \tag{Distrib}$$
$$=-a+(1\cdot a+(-1)\cdot a) \tag{MulIdent}$$
$$=-a+(a+(-1)\cdot a) \tag{AddAssoc}$$
$$=(-a+a)+(-1)\cdot a \tag{AddInv}$$
$$=0+(-1)\cdot a \tag{AddIdent}$$
$$=(-1)\cdot a$$

**Proposition 4**
$$(-a)^2=a^2   \tag{P4}$$

**Proof**
$$ (-a)^2 \tag{P3}$$
$$= ((-1)a)^2 \tag{def}$$
$$=((-1)a)((-1)a) \tag{MulAssoc}$$
$$=(((-1)a)(-1))a \tag{MulAssoc}$$
$$=((-1)(a(-1)))a \tag{MulComm}$$
$$=((-1)((-1)a))a \tag{MulAssoc}$$
$$=(((-1)(-1))a)a \tag{MulAssoc}$$
$$=((-1)(-1))(a\cdot a) \tag{def}$$
$$=(-1)^2a^2 \tag{P2}$$
$$=1\cdot a^2  \tag{MulIdent}$$
$$=a^2$$

**Proposition 5**
$$1>0 \tag{P5}$$
**Proof:**
$$1 \tag{MulIdent}$$
$$=1\cdot 1 \tag{OrdMulClose}$$
$$\ge 0 $$

**Proposition 6**
$$(-1)^2>0 \tag{P6}$$
**Proof:**
$$(-1)^2 \tag{P2}$$
$$=1\tag{P5}$$
$$\ge 0 $$

**Proposition 7**
$$a \ge 0 \Rightarrow a^2\ge0\tag{P7}$$
**Proof**

This follows from $(\text{OrdMulClose})$
if we replace $b$ by $a$.

**Proposition 8**
$$a \le 0 \Rightarrow a^2\ge0\tag{P8}$$ 
**Proof:**
We have 
$$a \le 0 \tag{OrdTranInv}$$
$$a+(-a) \le 0+(-a)$$
applying $(\text{AddInv})$ to the LHS and $(\text{AddIdent})$ to the RHS gives
$$0\le -a$$
which means 
$$-a \ge 0$$
So by $(\text{P7})$ we have
$$(-a)^2 \ge 0\tag{1}$$
From $(\text{P4})$
So we have 
$$a^2 =(-a)^2 \tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ follows
$$a^2\ge 0$$

**Proposition 9**
$$a^2\ge0\tag{P9}$$
**Proof:**
From $(\text{OrdTrich})$ we know that for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ holds
$$a<0 \; \lor a=0  \; \lor a>0 $$
So from $(\text{P7})$  and $(\text{P8})$ follows $(\text{P9})$

**Proposition 10**
$$a\ne0 \Rightarrow a^2\gt0\tag{P10}$$
**Proof:**
From $(\text{P9})$  we have
$$a^2\ge0$$
if 
$$a^2=0\tag{3}$$
and
$$a\ne 0\tag{4}$$
we can assume that there is $\frac 1 a$
and so from $(3)$ we get
$$\frac 1 a a^2=0\tag{MulAssoc}$$
$$\Rightarrow (\frac 1 a \cdot a) \cdot a=0\tag{MulInv}$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 \cdot a=0\tag{MulIdent}$$
$$\Rightarrow a=0$$
which contradicts $(\text{4})$

Comment: I feel like this answer conveys less meaning than it could due to the lack of words - if someone were looking to get a sense of how this proof goes, I think it would be difficult for them to do so from this because the properties are referred to only symbolically (i.e. never with their names) and because there are no words to highlight the structure of the proof - meaning it's difficult for a reader to, for instance, see how the ordered structure is applied. (Also, the symbolic proof is itself often unclear - the lines are often numerical expressions rather than logical expressions)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Maybe you are right in some points. I added an introduction and explained the purpose of the tags that differs depending of the context. This  was actually missing. I also changed the names of the axioms so tha is easy to deduce which axiom is meant,
I described the first step of proposition 1 in detail  But I think there is not more text necessary in propositions 1 to 6 and 8. There are only algebraic transformation. It is intended to avoid text. Formulas should be transformed in new formulas and the reader should avoid to associate the "true" interpretation to the symbols.

Comment: @MiloBrandt It is true that for proposition 1 to 6 and 8 the lines are numerical expression and not logical expression but I dont think that is a problem. this makes the proofs even simpler. I don't understand what you mean by structure of the proofs. There were some errors in the last propositions (P8), where equal signs were missing. I have added them The lines are actually numbers.